# React native call function once using onPress

Tags: react-native, mobile

I'm new with React native and when the user touch multiple times on the same component, the `onPress` event is called multiple times and also my method.

```
onPress={() => this.onItemPressed(type)}
```

I want to know what is the best way or one good existing way on React native to call this method just *one time* even if the user touch *multiple times* to don't break my app and load just one time if the user Touch in the component.

Thanks advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the button itself and wait for your logic to finish before enabling it or doing whatever action is next:

```
<Button
  onPress={() => this.onItemPressed(type)}
  disabled={this.state.itemPressedDisabled}>

onItemPressed(type) {
  this.setState({itemPressedDisabled: true})

  // ...code logic here

  // Use below if you want to enable the button again after you're done
  // this.setState({itemPressedDisabled: false})
}
```

Comment: At the time I was using local state for that purpose. I liked using the disabled property, which seems more straigh-forward since was built in for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is add a `disabled` state to your component. Set it to true if the code is executed and check every time on press if the `disabled` is false

Example:

```
onPress(){
    if( this.state.disabled === false ) {
        // TODO: Execute your code
        this.setState({ disabled: true })
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
onPress(){
    const { disabled } = this.state;
    if(!disabled){
        this.setState({ disabled: true })
        // Other logic or button functionality
    }    
}
```